# Eliminating CSS warnings in Visual Studio 2008 when class is used via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, visual-studio-2008, warnings

I have a few places where I use a class via jquery - for example, to add the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to a text file, my textbox declaration looks like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dateField" runat="server" CssClass="fieldSmall datePicker" />
```

However, this leads to a warning in VS2008 that the datePicker "class or CssClass value is not defined"

I doesn't feel right to create an emply CSS class just to elminiate this warning.  Is there another way to do it?

Comment: As I understand you, you are using the class for identification purposes for jQuery? A CSS class should be defined in CSS otherwise it is redundant. You could at least include your datePicker class in some kind of empty collection class, like `.datePicker, .otherRedundantClass, .andAnotherOne {}` Surely your datePickers will look different than other fields? Why not use your datePicker class then?

Comment: The "fieldSmall" class is used for the formatting, and is used for many different field types.  datePicker is only used to add the datepicker control to those fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to turn off HTML Validation:

- **Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Validation**
- Uncheck the "Show Errors" check box.

And CSS file error detection:

- **Tools > Options > Text Editor > CSS > CSS Specific**
- Uncheck "Detect Errors"

Comment: There's actually a checkbox under CSS Specific / Detect Errors for "Detect unknown properties" - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I handle it by creating an empty CSS class in a file I don't deploy in a released version like this:

```
<% #if DEBUG %>
  <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/style/jquery_style_classes.css") %>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% #endif %>
```

Then the jquery_style_classes.css contains simple empty classes

```
.datePicker {
}

.JqueryResizable {
}
```